# Remove unnecessary output from dask.dataframe.head()

Tags: pandas, dask

I ran the following piece of code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import csv
html_data=dd.read_csv('html_data.csv',quoting=3,error_bad_lines=False)
html_data.head()
```

The output was:

`b'Skipping line 5: expected 2 fields, saw 228\nSkipping line 6: expected 2 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 11: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line..........`

The output is displaying the first 5 rows of the dataset , but I want to remove the unnecessary information displayed before that.

Comment: That "unnecessary" information arises from `read_csv`, not `head`. It suggests that the header row of `html_data.csv` has only two columns (i.e., only one comma), but some data rows have a different number of columns. This can happen if your data contains natural-language strings with grammatical commas in them (user comments, addresses, etc.). What are the first few lines of `html_data.csv`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler you might consider changing this to an answer

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Actually the CSV file is an 8 GB file, so I can't open it directly or else the PC hangs.

Comment: @Ronith, if you're on Linux, you can use the `head` command to print only the first few lines of the file. If you're on Windows, I think your best hope to peek at the file without loading the whole thing is Cygwin or the Windows Subsystem for Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I'm on Linux, I'll give it a try.